# Auth::user()-> возвращает ноль

Tags: php, laravel

Пытаюсь разобраться с авторизацией в Laravel

Web.php

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
    // Здесь перечисляются маршруты, доступ к которым будет открыт только администраторам
       Route::get('auto', 'App\Http\Controllers\AutoController@getAuto')->name('all-auto');
    });
```

Middleware Admin.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;



use Closure;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Admin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin() ) // Проверка, авторизован ли пользователь, и присвоена ли ему роль "Администратор
        {
            return $next($request); // Если проверка пройдена, продолжаем работу
        }
        return redirect('/'); // Если проверка не пройдена, перебрасываем пользователя на главную страницу
    }
```

}

Model User.php isAdmin

```
public function role()
{   
  return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Role');
}
public function isAdmin()
{
   return $this->role()->where('name', 'admin')->first();
}
```

Kernel.php:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
    ];
```

При переходе на /auto кидает на /.  Auth::user()->isAdmin() возвращает NULL
В БД записи ролей имеются и присвоены пользователям.

Comment: Что за role, откуда она и как связана с User? Проверьте её связь - если она вам выдает NULL, то либо у этого пользователя нет этой роли, либо связь запрашивается неправильно.

Comment: Добавьте auth мидлварь перед админом, у вас запрос не авторизован на уровне мидлвара а вы уже пытаетесь проверить роль пользователя который ещё в этом мидлваре не факт что авторизован, и в мидлварах предерживайтесь user() реквеста

Comment: Ну и соответственно если у вас мидлвары зависят от других мидлваров то суйте их в группы а не пишите их в алиасы